# USB floppy is mounted readonly in Thunar

Tags: thunar, floppy

I have connected an USB floppy drive to my Xubuntu 17.04 machine.

The floppy shows up in Thunar for mounting but it is readonly afterwards.
The writeprotect tab on the disk is closed and I can write on the old machine I am exchanging data with.

My user account is member of both the floppy and plugdev group.
I tried chgrp or chmod on the mounted folder as root but it did not help.

What shall I do mount the floppy like other USB keys as read/write from within Thunar?